# IB doesn't detect wrong IBOutlet type

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Lets say I connect an `weak var myView: UIImageView!` outlet to an `UIImageView` instance in my XIB or Storyboard. Later I change the view class in IB to `UIView`. The outlet will still be connected without giving a warning or compile time error.

Can I somehow automatically detect such errors?

Answer (score 2):

UIView is parent class of UIImageView, so you can connect UIImageView with UIView but you can't connect a UIView to UIImageView.
So technically, it is not an error.

Comment: If I connect an `UIView` to an `UIImageView` outlet it is definitely an error. No `UIView` can ever be an `UIImageView`. You're thinking the wrong way round.